# Error al instalar MySQL 8 en Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Quiero instalar MySQL 8 en Ubuntu 8 y sigo estos pasos:

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
```

Tras ejecutar el último paso indicado, parece este error:

```
root@92r6bf82:/tmp# sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.17-1ubuntu16.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el problema?

Gracias

Tras hacer:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i mysql
```

Este es el resultado:

```
rc  libmysqlclient18:amd64    5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                   amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  mysql-apt-config          0.8.10-1                                  all          Auto configuration for MySQL APT Repo.
ii  php7.2-mysql              7.2.21-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1     amd64        MySQL module for PHP
```

Con esto:

```
apt-cache search mysql-community-server
```

Este es el resultado:

```
mysql-community-server - MySQL Server
mysql-community-server-core - MySQL Server Core Binaires
mysql-community-server-core-dbgsym - Debugging symbols for server core
mysql-community-server-debug - Debug binaries for MySQL Server
mysql-community-server-debug-dbgsym - Debugging symbols for server debug binaries
```

¿Cómo puedo eliminar los restos de la instalación anterior?

Ejecuto:

```
apt-get remove --purge libmysqlclient18:amd64
```

y

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Intento instalar de nuevo. Parece que da el mismo problema:

```
root@92r6bf82:~# apt-get remove --purge libmysqlclient18:amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  libmysqlclient18*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 120891 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...



root@92r6bf82:~# sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/mariadb/repo/10.4/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/mariadb/repo/10.3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done



root@92r6bf82:~# wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
--2019-08-23 17:48:21--  https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
Resolving dev.mysql.com (dev.mysql.com)... 137.254.60.11
Connecting to dev.mysql.com (dev.mysql.com)|137.254.60.11|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb [following]
--2019-08-23 17:48:21--  https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
Resolving repo.mysql.com (repo.mysql.com)... 23.210.47.26
Connecting to repo.mysql.com (repo.mysql.com)|23.210.47.26|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 35970 (35K) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb’

mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb          100%[=====================================================================================>]  35.13K  --.-KB/s    in 0.001s

2019-08-23 17:48:21 (42.0 MB/s) - ‘mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb’ saved [35970/35970]



root@92r6bf82:~# sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-apt-config.
(Reading database ... 120891 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-apt-config (0.8.10-1) ...
Setting up mysql-apt-config (0.8.10-1) ...
OK



root@92r6bf82:~# sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/mariadb/repo/10.4/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial InRelease [21.6 kB]
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://nyc2.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://mirror.nodesdirect.com/mariadb/repo/10.3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:7 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial/mysql-8.0 Sources [1,030 B]
Get:8 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial/mysql-apt-config amd64 Packages [564 B]
Get:9 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial/mysql-apt-config i386 Packages [564 B]
Hit:6 http://mariadb.mirror.liquidtelecom.com/repo/10.3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:10 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial/mysql-8.0 amd64 Packages [7,426 B]
Get:11 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial/mysql-8.0 i386 Packages [7,463 B]
Get:12 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial/mysql-tools amd64 Packages [4,324 B]
Get:13 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu xenial/mysql-tools i386 Packages [3,587 B]
Fetched 46.6 kB in 1s (35.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.



root@92r6bf82:~# sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.17-1ubuntu16.04) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comprobación de paquetes de mariadb:

```
root@92r6bf82:~# dpkg -l | grep -i mariadb
root@92r6bf82:~#
```

Comment: ¿Podrías hacer un `dpkg -l | grep -i mysql`? Parece de que tienes instalada una versión previa que tiene dependencias diferentes y rompe la instalación.

Comment: También deberías probar un `apt-cache search mysql-community-server` para comprobar que instalaste correctamente el paquete anterior (`sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb`) y posteriormente hiciste correctamente el `apt-get update`. Si tardaste mucho tiempo entre el `apt-get update` y el `apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client`, te recomiendo volver a ejecutar un `apt-get update` porque en ocasiones puedes estar tratando de descargar una versión de un paquete que ya no se encuentra en los repositorios (aunque previamente hace el intento de descargarlo y luego te da el fallo).

Comment: En mi pregunta pongo los resultados de lo que me indicáis.

Comment: Está bien, parece que no hay ningún paquete conflictivo. Borra definitivamente el paquete de la versión 5.5 con `apt-get remove --purge libmysqlclient18:amd64`. Tras eso prueba un update e install de nuevo.

Comment: He ampliado mi pregunta con lo que sale. Gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: Acabo de ver repositorios del servidor MariaDB, deberías desinstalar también todo lo relacionado con él. Echa un vistazo a `dpkg -l | grep -i mariadb` para ver qué puede haber instalado relacionado con dicho servidor y así poder desinstalarlo.

Comment: Parece que no hay nada de mariadb

Comment: No puedo seguir ayudando hasta la noche, estoy fuera de casa. Más tarde te daré un par de instrucciones para listar todos los repositorios y paquetes instalados para ver qué puede estar pasando. También instalaré en un docker de Ubuntu 16.04 lo mismo que tú para intentar reproducir el problema.

Comment: Gracias, de verdad.

Comment: He ejecutado dpkg --get-selections y no veo nada con el texto mariadb y con mysql estos: mysql-apt-config y php7.2-mysql

Comment: Esos dos son normales, uno es el que instalas con `dpkg` y el otro se necesita para que PHP haga uso de MySQL.

Comment: No he conseguido reproducir tu problema de dependencias en una instalación limpia de Ubuntu 16.04 a través de una imagen Docker. [Este es el histórico de ejecución de instrucciones](https://gist.github.com/ojgarciab/3e883c7d4130506a1aa93142ffe47587). Para intentar comunicarnos mejor y no saturar tu pregunta con más comentarios, [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97819/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-paco-s).

Answer (score 2):

Puedes *forzar* el borrado de todo el sistema MySQL **no compatible** con Ubuntu 16.04, para instalar desde cero la versión recomendada .
(recuerda que si tienes bases de datos, debes exportarlas antes para tener respaldo)

1. borrar

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql\*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get -y autoremove
sudo apt-get -y autoclean
```

2. (opcional) reinicia sesión y/o máquina

```
sudo reboot
```

3. instalar

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

> sudo apt-get install -f

En caso de no funcionar prueba con:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Esto sirve para corregir dependencias que no pudieron ser satisfechas en los `dpkg -i <paquete>` previos, pero no sirve para resolver dependencias de un nuevo `apt-get install <paquetes>`. Esta respuesta deberías haberla publicado como comentario.

Comment: Madre mía es cierto. Bueno, ¡gracias por el aviso!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
dpkg –configure -a
```

Lo que hace el comando es que completa la configuracion y encuentra los paquetes rotos por instalaciones incompletas anteriormente. 
y ademas deberia instalarte el mysql sin que tengas que hacer nada.

Comment: Tras ejecutar, me aparece esto:

dpkg: error: need an action option

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and uninstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !

Comment: Lo ejecuto así y parece que se ejecuta bien: dpkg --configure -a. Intento instalar de nuevo y da el mismo error.

Comment: Tengo entendido que te lo instala el solo, de todas formas prueba asi: ( dpkg -configure mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb  -a ) y me cuentas

Comment: dpkg -configure mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb -a


dpkg: error: unknown option -o

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and uninstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !

Comment: Disiento en la descripción que das de la instrucción. Su misión es completar la configuración de aquellos paquetes desempaquetados pero no instalados por, por ejemplo, una instalación previa cancelada (en esta parte sí que tienes razón), pero en ningún momento actualiza el paquete si no fue detenida una actualización y fue una instalación nueva ni "encuentra" paquetes rotos. Si se produce un error de dependencias durante una instalación limpia no hay nada que configurar ni ningún paquete a medio instalar.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Tienes toda la razon, lamento mi lenguaje tan "coloquial" con actualizar me referia a reparar el paquete roto, o a acabarlo de configurar como bien apuntas tu. lo edito